# Font awesome some icons not working

Tags: css, fonts

I've set up the new version 4.4.0 of font-awesome with the 'fa fa-' classes and I get mixed results. While most icons work, some just don't display like 'fa fa-copyright'.
I see in the console that font-awesome.min.css is loaded,

When I set up a CDN file of the font-awesome that icons will be displayed.

I also tried copy CDN file and paste it to our download file font-awesome.min.css but result are same

Comment: give the container class the rule: `font-family: 'FontAwesome'` and see if it works, otherwise you might have to reproduce the problem in jsfiddle or provide a live link. Also, make sure you have the font files loaded in your fonts folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the right font files i.e. the .eot, .svg... (in addition to the css) and in the right path.